# Importing MySQL database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mediatemple

I'm trying to import a mysql database into my grid service account at media temple.

I've made a blank database, but there are already lots of tables there such as:

```
CHARACTER_SETS
CLIENT_STATISTICS
COLLATIONS
COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY
COLUMNS
COLUMN_PRIVILEGES
ENGINES
EVENTS
FILES
GLOBAL_STATUS
GLOBAL_TEMPORARY_TABLES
GLOBAL_VARIABLES
```

What are these prexisting tables? How do I get rid of them so I can import my database

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking at the database created by MySQL for its own use, called `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

You have to create a database with `CREATE DATABASE YOURNAMEHERE;` and then put your database tables in that database.

Check out a good introductory tutorial in MySQL, like http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tutorial.html